# What SSL options should not be used?

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography, hmac, asymmetric

What SSL options should be avoided, due to recently discovered weaknesses? This might include symmetric algorithms, or MAC functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should avoid the "weak" cipher suites:

- Cipher suites with no encryption (with a `NULL` in the name).
- Cipher suites with 40-bit or 56-bit symmetric keys (`DES`, `DES40`, `RC4_40`, `RC2_CBC_40`)(`3DES` is fine, though).
- Cipher suites marked "for export" (with `EXPORT` in the name: they are weakened to comply with pre-2000 US export regulations).
- Cipher suites with no server authentication (`DH_anon`).

No sane software will enable these by default, or at all. But it is safer to check explicitly...

You may want to avoid RC4 because of the bad press (it still takes some *millions* of connections with the same encrypted data to hit the known weaknesses, which is not a huge security margin, but the attack is not really practical yet). Some people want to avoid CBC-based block ciphers because they fear the BEAST, but [it does not work any more](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34137/beast-mitigation-on-a-cisco-ace-4710-load-balancer/34146#34146). Similarly, use of MD5 in SSL/TLS is safe, but the idea that "MD5 is broken" is so widespread that using MD5 tends to trigger questions and justifications and endless debate. In practice, your system won't be broken into because you used RC4 or MD5 or AES-CBC or any other non-weak cipher suite; we are in the realm of *public relations* here.

Among possible options, you should avoid **compression** unless you make sure that it does not apply to your exact context; this is because encryption hides data *contents* but not data *length*, and compression makes length dependent on the contents. In a Web context (HTTPS), this is called the [CRIME attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19911/crime-how-to-beat-the-beast-successor/19914#19914).

If possible (depending on your server software and server certificate), try to use the `DHE` cipher suites: they provide [Perfect Forward Secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy). Said otherwise: if you use a non-DHE cipher suite, and some bad guy manages to steal your server private key, then he will be able to decrypt *past* connections (connections which the attacker observed passively, from the outside, before the actual key theft). PFS is about avoiding that. (But, of course, PFS or not PFS, it is much better if your server private key is not stolen at all.)

[Don't use SSL 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6176). In practice, SSL 2.0 still offers some decent protection against *passive* attackers, but active attackers can play nasty tricks. If your client and server software supports SSL 2.0 but not SSL 3.0 or TLS (1.0 or ulterior), then your software is more than 15 years old and almost certainly has a lot of other problems.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to above answers, one of the services you can use is https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ , which will test the SSL/TLS settings and right away report you of violations. This way you can quickly audit your settings quickly (Unless you have some scripts ready to do so).

Note : I am no way associated with SSLLabs.

Answer (score 0):

The RC4 option should not be used.

Not only is it old (from 1987, ancient even), but it is also suffering from minor security problems.

Still is it often enabled since other (more modern and heavier attacked) algorithms recently got bad news. RC4 is somewhat predictable though and repeatedly (say 20 thousand times) requesting the same webpages via https will show patterns, thus allowing you to compromise security.

[Edit] Added [link to attack-of-week-rc4-is-kind-of-broken-in.html](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2013/03/attack-of-week-rc4-is-kind-of-broken-in.html)